# How can I sample the data for all each category ramdomly?

Tags: python, numpy

I have some data and corresponding labels labels like below:

```
data = [img1, img2, img3, ...]    # each category has 1000 samples, total data is 10000
labels = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, ...]    # total num of labels is 10
```

I want to make new sub dataset which have one category has 1000 samples, and other categories has 100 samples respectively. So the number of total data in sub dataset will be 1900. (1000 vs 900)

(My intend is to make sub dataset for binary classification)

So I need to sample the data ramdomly for all each category with same amount.

I think it is similar with stratified sampling so I tried to find method in scikit-learn, but I couldn't.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a function either so I made one.

Let's make a bogus dataset:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.choice(np.arange(10), 10_000)
```

Now, let's find indexes that will return equally stratified samples, if taken from `x`.

```py
d = dict()

for val in np.unique(x):
    d[str(val)] = np.where(x == val)
    d[str(val)] = np.random.choice(d[str(val)][0], 100, replace=False)

ix = np.concatenate([values for values in d.values()])
```

Let's test it:

```
print(np.unique(x[ix], return_counts=True))
```

```
Out[64]: 
(array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
 array([100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100], dtype=int64))
```

You can also use `ix` with your `y`, or any other array.

Comment: Thanks to your answer!